# findin() function not supported in Julia v1.1.1

Tags: dataframe, julia

findin(a,b) was a function supported in Julia v0.6.2. However, it was exchanged for another function in Julia 1.0, findall((in)(b),a). The following code worked in Julia v0.6.2

```
df_temp = df[findin(df[:pmid],pmids),:]
```

However when I attempt the same in with the findall((in)b,a) function in Julia 1.1.1 as below;

```
df_temp = df[findall((in)(pmids),df[:pmid]),:]
```

I received the following error.

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching parse(::SubString{String}) Closest candidates are:  
  parse(!Matched::Type{DecFP.Dec32}, !Matched::AbstractString) at C:\Users\Thor\.julia\packages\DecFP\3jJW7\src\DecFP.jl:224  
  parse(!Matched::Type{LibGit2.GitCredential}, !Matched::AbstractString) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win32\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\LibGit2\src\gitcredential.jl:73
  parse(!Matched::Type{LibGit2.GitCredentialHelper}, !Matched::AbstractString) at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win32\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.1\LibGit2\src\gitcredential.jl:163

Stacktrace:
  [1] _broadcast_getindex_evalf at .\broadcast.jl:578 [inlined]
  [2] _broadcast_getindex at .\broadcast.jl:551 [inlined] 
  [3] getindex at .\broadcast.jl:511 [inlined]
  [4] copy at .\broadcast.jl:787 [inlined]
  [5] materialize(::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{1},Nothing,typeof(parse),Tuple{Array{SubString{String},1}}}) at .\broadcast.jl:753
  [6] get_features_labels(::DataFrame, ::Array{Int32,1}) at C:\Users\Thor\Documents\MachineLearning\Work\classifiers.jl:208
  [7] test_analysis_skl(::DataFrame, ::Array{Int32,1}, ::Array{Int32,1}, ::Symbol, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at C:\Users\Thor\Documents\Machine Learning\Work\crossval_and_stats.jl:24
  [8] main() at C:\Users\Thor\Documents\MachineLearning\Work\machine_learning_regsampling.jl:79
  [9] top-level scope at none:0
 [10] include at .\boot.jl:326 [inlined]
 [11] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1038
 [12] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
 [13] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:267
 [14] _start() at .\client.jl:436 in expression starting at C:\Users\Thor\Documents\MachineLearning\Work\machine_learning_regsampling.jl:181
```

I was wondering if you had any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example as the error message seems to indicate some other problem than `findall` function. Also you can just write `in(pmids)` and it is recommended to write `df.pmid` instead of `df[:pmid]` as the latter might get deprecated in the future.

Comment: That stack trace does not look like the problem is coming from `findin`.  The problem is in the broadcasted expression you wrote on `C:\Users\Thor\Documents\MachineLearning\Work\classifiers.jl:208`, likely calling `parse`.  You likely want to use `Meta.parse` instead.  Use Julia 0.7 to identify these sorts of changes when upgrading code from 0.6.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński apologies, I posted the wrong error. I will update df[:pmid] to df.pmid.

Comment: Why don't you use `filter` instead? `df_temp = filter(x -> x.pmid in pmids, df)`? Or use `Iterators.filter` to avoid allocating the new df.